# Many to many relationship when join table takes two same entities and an additional one

Tags: postgresql, database-design, normalization

as of right now I'm trying to design a database which contains data involving football matches. I have two tables: Match & Football Team both containing various attributes. These are connected via many to many relationship. As far as I understand, I need a join table. In that table, I would need to contain ID of the match and IDs of both teams. Am I right or is this design flawed? I'm just a beginner when it comes to databases so I would appreciate some help.

[image]

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how/why you are 1st stuck on what step among which steps following what published presentation of what design method/process given what? Right now you are essentially asking us to (re)write a textbook with bespoke tutorial with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs. PS Your diagram does not agree with your prose description, and is not a reasonable design.

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs. [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. An ERD is an illustration of DDL.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Why have two match tables? I'd do something more like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/DMFGTAtZ).

Answer (score 2):

Data model is often a matter of opinion, so here's mine: there is no "many to many" relationship between teams and matches; there is "many to exactly two". In other words, the home and away teams are attributes of a match; a match would be meaningless without either. Subsequently, you don't need the junction table.